# Create Dynamic Routing with Dynamic Prefix Group and Dynamic Controller Call

Tags: php, laravel

Hope you all are doing well. I apologize for my English (I'm not a native speaker).
Let's jump right to the matter. I'm relatively new to Laravel and I can't accomplish what I want to do.

What I want to accomplish is:
I'm building a little CMS and I have an Entry table in which I store content as blog posts but also as projects for my portfolio. Currently, I can show these two modules of entries separated from each other in the public front-end at *~/blog/post* (for posts) and *~/portfolio/projects*.( for projects).

I thought of them as separated modules or domains, as you prefer to call them.

Now the tricky part. In my ~/admin I create a dynamic routing to get these modules and other modules like Users, Menus, Roles, Tags, Categories, this way:

```
Route::get('{module}', function($module) 
  {
   return App::make('App\Http\Controllers\Admin\\'.ucfirst($module).'Controller')->Index();
)->name('module');
```

Ok, that worked well until I added CRUD ops to the Entries (posts and projects). The first thing I did was create separated controllers, but I thought "I don't want to repeat code", so I thought on use inheritance or interfaces but I'm not comfortable yet on how to do it in php.

So, What I want is to maintain separated all entries marked as projects from the ones marked as posts but use the same EntryController for all CRUD ops, I thought passing the "module name or id" to the controller as a parameter or make the routing dynamic but I feel blocked. I did some research on how I could accomplish this and found something like this:

```
Route::Group(['prefix' => '/{module}', 'as' => 'module' ], function()
{
    Route::get('', function($module) 
    {
        return App::make('App\Http\Controllers\Admin\\'.ucfirst($module).'Controller')->Index();
    })->name('module.index');

    Route::get('/{id}', function($module) {
        return App::make('App\Http\Controllers\Admin\\'.ucfirst($module).'Controller')->Delete();
    }) 
    ->name("delete.{module}");

// ..... AND THE REST OF THE OPERATIONS FOLLOWS THE SAME LOGIC .....
```

I try this too but this work having /Admin/BlogController and /Admin/PortfolioController (and is what I want to improve)

```
$module = ['blog','portfolio'];
foreach($module as $entry)
{
          Route::post('', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\\'.ucfirst($entry).'Controller@CreateEntry')
            ->name("create.{$entry}");
         
            Route::post('/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\\'.ucfirst($entry).'Controller@DeleteEntry')
            ->name("delete.{$entry}");

// ............... MORE CRUD OPS .......................
    });
```

I'm feeling stuck, I'll be deeply thankful if someone can give me a hand on this.
Thank you in advance for reading me :) best wishes to you.

**PD: This is giving me trouble because I'm trying to maintain the url as clean as possible (e.g, ~/admin/portfolio, ~/admin/blog, ~/admin/users, ~/admin/roles, etc)**

Comment: what is not working here actually??

Comment: Hello Zahid, hope you're doing well. Well having the first option I posted, when I try to get to ~/admin in which I show all modules, It throws me an exception, saying that the route "module" is not defined. I tried changing the name but got the same exception. 

PD: I saw the code and find out that I declared the type of http methods incorrectly, so I fix that but without any success. I'll continue today working on that if I find a workaround I'll post here :), Thanks for being interested. greetings